# undefined method `slug_limit=' for friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

When I set the `slug_limit` on [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) as per the documentation in the initializer, I see the following error:

```
Failure/Error: extend FriendlyId

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `slug_limit=' for #<#<Class:0x00007ffe66dd01a0>:0x00007ffe66dd0150>
# ./config/initializers/friendly_id.rb:68:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

My model implements friendly_id like this:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]
```

How do I set the slug limit?

Comment: I cant find a method "slug_limit", could you send me the doc link?

Comment: What is in `config/initializers/friendly_id.rb`? And as mentioned above, I can't see any reference to `slug_limit` in the documentation -- so what is this code expected to be doing?

Comment: Ah wait, I've just seen [this](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/819c0b111b0f722809c0a13ad025c5191a278f85/lib/friendly_id/initializer.rb#L63), which you presumably uncommented in your generated initializer? Maybe this is only valid id you also specify `config.use :slugged`? Like I said, it would be helpful to see that whole configuration file, rather than me guessing what it might say.

Comment: Or maybe you're using an **old version** of the gem, that does not have the [`slug_limit`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/pull/809) feature?? Which version of the gem are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set `slug_limit` like this from the [test example](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/e118abe07ef427a3a6affdaacf7efbcc5e259218/test/slugged_test.rb#L340):

```rb
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged, slug_limit: 40
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. It took me a while to find. Thanks!